# Letter 'u' problems

Tags: windows

The <kbd>U</kbd> key brings up the Utility manager every time I use it. This is a huge problem, since my password for the computer administrator contains "u", and I cannot get rid of or change anything about the Utility Mgr in the guest account. The on-screen keyboard works, but the <kbd>U</kbd> key will not work on it.  Help!

Comment: Make sure the windows key isn't stuck. Win + U is the shortcut for utility manager.

Answer (score 7):

Utility manager is opened when pressing <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>. It seems your <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd> is stuck.
Can you lock your machine by pressing <kbd>L</kbd>?

Try, in the following order:

- Press and release the <kbd>WindowsKey</kbd>
- Plug out your keyboard and plug it back it (maybe in a different USB port)
- Reboot
- Clean or repair your keyboard
- Get a new keyboard